Failed create CLMM using Token 2022 - Raydium Concentrated Liquidity: OpenPositionV2 (Program Error: "null")
I will add liquidity from the tokens I built in token 2022 using CLMM according to this question How to create a Liquidity pool for a token 2022 token
After I entered “Confirm Deposit” and the gas fee was deducted, it failed with this error message (#5 - Raydium Concentrated Liquidity: OpenPositionV2
(Program Error: “null”))
signature: https://solscan.io/tx/2nPKxNenW6Nx1jxGPg3umF3ThBKgfdH7XzVX9f4XpzuRmYVWcTfRQu5wVnwZ2zr9wPJ9LS6s98zXLNCg3xAdsaE9
What is the cause of this and what is the future solution?
Thank you

According to the program logs, you have insufficient funds for the transfer
The log messages
Invoking System Program
  > Transfer: insufficient lamports 63964291, need 72161280
  > Program returned error: custom program error: 0x1
> Program Raydium Concentrated Liquidity consumed

